# My PHP file doesn't execute in the browser

Tags: php

Nothing appears in the browser when I open this file. I assumed it's supposed to show "it works," but instead it shows nothing when the file is opened in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<?php

echo "It works";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your Apache is stoped!start all services

Comment: if Apache was stopped, the output would be cannot connect to the server.

Comment: Are you sure you have php enabled on your server? create a new file called test.php and place the content inside below:

<?php 
  phpinfo(); 
?>

Comment: PHP "executes" on the server, not in the browser. Is your http server configured to handle PHP?

Comment: im hoping you named the page with a .php extension and called the page directly.

Answer (score 1):

PHP files are executed in Server , You need a local host server like LAMP or [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) needed to execute a PHP script

Answer (score 1):

1. php files are executed in Server. After you installed Wamp, put your php code in `www` folder name as `test.php`, and go to `localhost/test.php` in your browser, you will see `it works`
2. when you open a file directly in your browser, it is treated as html file. the url would be like `file:///D:/web/hello.html`. But
   `<?php ... ?>` is not valid html so you got a blank page.

some links that might be useful to you

- [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
- [install and testing wamp](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. If you want any php page to execute then definitely you need server whether it is virtually created or it is real. You are trying to run the php page directly which has no meaning to browser. You may use software like **Wamp, Xamp** that creates a virtual server on your PC. Try using this, then come back if you face any problem. For more info on how to use these, just **GOOGLE** them. You'll find millions of solutions there. Good Luck!